# How to pass boolean parameter to HQL new constructor

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

**Situation**: I have an object **SubjectRow** that wraps object **Subject** (object Subject is persistable entity). I need to create new wrapper object directly in HQL.

```
public class SubjectRow{
    Subject subject;
    String myString;
    boolean myBoolean;

    public SubjectRow(SubjectSch subject, String myString) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    public SubjectRow(SubjectSch subject, boolean myBoolean) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.myBoolean = myBoolean;
    }


}
```

**HQL for constructor with string (and it works like it should):**

```
SELECT new package.SubjectRow(s, 'myString') FROM Subject s
```

**Problem**. The problem that sometimes I need to call another constructor of this wrapper that accepts boolean instead of string. I tried the same approach

```
SELECT new package.SubjectRow(s, true) FROM Subject s
```

But Hibernate complains that it can't find appropriate constructor in class SubjectRow. Of course, I could pass string and then just make appropriate casting - but its too ugly.

**Question**: how should I change my HQL and/or constructor to pass this boolean parameter directly (it is possible to use Boolean instead)?

**"Solution"**. Because I was unable to find how to pass boolean correctly I have to rework my domain objects little bit. I just remove this boolean property from SubjectRow and instead create SubjectRowFalse and SubjectRowTrue classes that are children of original object. And now just using two HQL

```
SELECT new package.SubjectRowTrue(s) FROM Subject s

SELECT new package.SubjectRowFalse(s) FROM Subject s
```

Of course, it is just a workaround and not solution for the original problem

Comment: I don't have an answer, but you don't *need* to call this constructor from the HQL query. You just need 3 lines of Java code to call the constructor explicitely, and have code that will be refactorable as an added bonus.

Comment: Actually I need. I have to pass HQL String and this wrapper must be constructed in this string

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think that you might need to use a Boolean object instead of the boolean primitive.

Comment: Tried that one. Without result. Property in class was like Boolean myBoolean with appropriate getters and setters and usage in constructor. In the HQL it looks like "SubjectRow(s, java.lang.Boolean.TRUE)". But I get the same exception - constructor is undefined.